# Error in mysql syntax when using parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters

I keep getting told that there are errors in my mysql syntax when I'm using parameters.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim db As New Database

    Dim sql As String = "select firstname, password from users where email = :email"

    Dim args As New List(Of MySqlParameter)
    args.Add(New MySqlParameter(":email", txtEmail.Text))

    ' execDB(procedurename As String, proceduretype As String, parameters() as MySqlParameter, returntype As String, newconnection As Boolean)

    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = db.execDB(sql, "Text", args.ToArray, "DataReader", False)
```

The error states that `:email` is not a valid value. I don't understand why it's not using the parameter as I'm passing it to the `execDB` function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?param` [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters),

```
Dim sql As String = "select firstname, password from users where email = ?email"
```

Comment: Well it worked, can you explain why? I'm a little confused as I've used `:email` in other places and those all seemed to work fine

Comment: @Ortund - :param is not valid for mysql connect API. Take a look at documentation (syntax).